# Is "Escherian metamorphosis" always possible?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, tessellations, hausdorff-distance

*This question is motivated by Escher's series of **Metamorphosis** woodcuts (see e.g. [here](https://www.escherinhetpaleis.nl/story-of-escher/metamorphosis-i-ii-iii/?lang=en)), where one tesselating tile is gradually transformed into another. Basically, this is a precise way of asking the following: can we always "metamorphose" between any pair of tesselating shapes? (Now [asked in modified form at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433479/is-escherian-metamorphosis-always-possible).)*

---

First, some definitions (everything is in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the usual metric):

- A *shape* is a compact connected set $X$ with $X=cl(int(X))$.
- A *tiling* is a pair $(\mathscr{S},F)$ where $\mathscr{S}$ is a finite set of shapes and $F$ is a set of functions such that

  - each $f\in F$ is an isometric embedding of some $S\in\mathscr{S}$ into $\mathbb{R}^2$,
  - $\bigcup_{f\in F}ran(f)=\mathbb{R}^2$, and
  - if $f,g\in F$ are distinct with domains $S,T$ respectively and $x\in int(S)$, then $f(x)\not\in ran(g)$ ("shapes only meet at their boundaries").
- A *tile* is a shape $X$ such that $(\{X\},F)$ is a tiling for some $F$.
- $d_H$ is [Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance). *(Note that we could replace $d_H$ with the modified version $d_{H*}(U,V)$ = the infimum over planar isometries $p$ of $d_H(p(U), V)$ without changing the question substantively; all that would change is that the number of tiles needed would shrink, but I'm not looking at that here.)*

Now with apologies to Escher, given tiles $A,B$ and $\epsilon>0$ an **$\epsilon$-metamorphism** from $A$ to $B$ is a tiling $(\mathscr{S},F)$ such that

- if $f\in F$ and $(x,y)\in ran(f)$ with $x<0$ then $dom(f)=A$,
- there is some $N$ such that if $g\in F$ and $(x,y)\in ran(g)$ with $x>N$ then $dom(g)=B$ (call the least such $N$ the *length* of the $\epsilon$-metamorphism), and
- if $f,g\in F$ and $ran(f)\cap ran(g)\not=0$ then $d_H(dom(f), dom(g))<\epsilon$.

> **Question**: is there always an $\epsilon$-metamorphism between $A$ and $B$ for any tiles $A,B$ and any positive $\epsilon$?

I recall seeing a theorem that the answer is **yes**, and that moreover we can always find metamorphisms with length "close to" the naive guess $$\max\{diam(A),diam(B)\}\cdot d_H(A,B)\over \epsilon.$$ However, I haven't been able to track it down or prove it myself. I'm also interested in whether the situation changes as we appropriately tweak things to work in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n>2$.

Comment: I'm having difficulty imagining how to do this if $A$ and $B$ are regular hexagons with $A$ having side length $1$ and $B$ having side length $\pi$ or something, but I have no idea how you would prove that this does not work.

Comment: @JamesHanson: This case is not too bad; you can make the vertical "zigzags" gradually less bendy until you have a series of rectangles, then stretch the rectangles to their new heights and expand the zigzags back out. In general any $A$ and $B$ that tile by translation will be easy to metamorphose into each other. What I worry about is something like the [15th pentagonal tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_tiling#Mann/McLoud/Von_Derau_\(2015\)_Type_15); I don't see a way to metamorphose from this into literally any other monohedral tiling (even a scaled vertion of itself).

Comment: The "Hausdoff Distance" link gives the Metamorphosis I,II,II link instead. I assume that's a copy/paste error. Did you have another site in mind?

Comment: Without the length condition, you can always construct a metamorphosis by shrinking the tiles to arbitrarily small sizes so that the Hausdorff distance condition fails to bind.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Fixed, thanks!

Comment: @JacobManaker: I thought about this construction, but I don't see how you actually get it to work - how do you avoid the tiles separating arbitrarily far at extreme $y$-values?

Comment: @JacobManaker I don't quite see the details, but I strongly suspect that that works. I've tweaked the MO version to address this, but I'll leave this version as is.